# Model is null on postback in ajax loaded partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco

I'm using the following pattern https://github.com/filamentgroup/Ajax-Include-Pattern
to load partial views through ajax.

View:

```
    @using(Html.BeginUmbracoForm("PostContactInformation", "JoiningSurface", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "joinform" } })) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div data-append="@Url.Action("RenderJoiningContactInformation", "JoiningSurface", new { ContentId = CurrentPage.Id })"></div>
    }
```

With Action:

```
 public ActionResult RenderContactInformation(int ContentId)
       {
            var viewModel = ContactViewModel();
            viewModel.Content = Umbraco.TypedContent(ContentId);

            return PartialView("RenderContactInformation", viewModel);
        }
```

Loads partial view perfectly.

// No need to add partial view i think

Post action works correctly as well:

```
public ActionResult PostContactInformation(ContactViewModel model)  
{
//code here
    return RedirectToUmbracoPage(pageid);
}
```

The problem is, that i need to add model error to CurrentUmbracoPage if it exists in post...

For example:

```
public ActionResult PostContactInformation(ContactViewModel model)  
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error occurred");
    return CurrentUmbracoPage();
}
```

In this case i get null values for current model. And this happens only when i use ajax.

If i load action synchronously like that:

```
   @using(Html.BeginUmbracoForm("PostJoiningContactInformation", "JoiningSurface", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "joinform" } })) {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.Action("RenderContactInformation", "JoiningSurface", new { ContentId = CurrentPage.Id })
            }
```

everything works like it should.

But i need to use ajax. Is there a correct way to pass values on postback in this case? I know that i can use TempData, but i'm not sure that this is the best approach. 
Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Umbraco context is not accessible when you're trying to reach it through ajax call. Those calls are a little bit different.

Check my answer in this thread: [Umbraco route definition-ajax form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436208/umbraco-route-definition-ajax-form/39451042#39451042) and I suggest to go with WebAPI and UmbracoApiControllers to be able to access those values during the Ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Marcin!